# extract multiples columns from txt file perl

Tags: arrays, perl, extract

I have a txt file like this:

```
#Genera columnA columnB columnC columnD columnN
x1       1       3       7      0.9      2
x2       5       3       13     7        5
x3       0.1     0.8     7      1        0.4
```

and I want to extract X determinate number of columns, just suppose that we want columnA, columnC and columnN (this could be a matrix with  1, 2, 20, 100 or more columns) and What I want to print OUT (this example is just 3 but could be more):

```
#Genera columnA columnC columnN
    x1   1       7       2
    x2   5       13      5
    x3   0.1     7       0.4
```

I have tried

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my @wanted_fields = qw/columnA columnC columnN/;

open DATA, '<', "columns.txt" or die "cant open file\n";


my @datain = <DATA>;
close DATA;

my (@unit_name, $names, @lines, @conteo, @match_names, @columnas);

foreach (@datain){
    if ($_=~ m/^$/g)            {   next;           }
    elsif ($_=~ m/#Genera/g)    {   $names= $_;     }
    else                        {   push @lines, $_ }
}


@unit_name = split (/\t/, $names);
shift @unit_name;
my $count =0;

    foreach (@wanted_fields){
        my $unit_wanted =$_;
        chomp $unit_wanted;
        foreach (@unit_name){
            if ($_ =~ m/$unit_wanted/g){
                $count++;
                 push (@conteo, $count);
                 push (@match_names, $_);
                }
        }
    }


    foreach (@lines){
        chomp;
        @columnas = split (/\t/, $_);
            #push @xx, $columnas[0][3];

    }
```

I used the count to determinate the column to extract but in this case the number 2 do no correspond to columnC and 3 do not correspond to columnN well...... it is a any simple way to select any given columns, in this case I just want 3 but depend of the case could be 1,2 5, 10, 100 or more columns.

Thanks

Comment: can you add the line with the print and the result you got ? :)

Comment: its a tab delimit?

Comment: yeah, forgot that, if the "space" can vary between all possibles espacements (tab, space, \n, ...) use \s+ instead of \t ;)
Don't think this is the reason your code fails, but it could be useful for further use :)

Comment: `DATA` is a special file handle in perl. You probably shouldn't use that.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify like this and using [hash slices](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @wanted = ( '#Genera' , qw (  columnA columnC columnN ));

open my $input, '<', "file.txt" or die $!;

chomp ( my @header = split ' ', <$input> ); 

print join "\t", @wanted, "\n";
while ( <$input> ) { 
   my %row;
   @row{@header} = split; 
   print join "\t", @row{@wanted}, "\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
#Genera columnA columnC columnN 
x1  1   7   2   
x2  5   13  5   
x3  0.1 7   0.4
```

If you want to exactly match your indentation then add `sprintf` to the mix:

E.g.:

```
print join "\t", map { sprintf "%8s", $_} @wanted, "\n";
while ( <$input> ) { 
   my %row;
   @row{@header} = split; 
   print join "\t", map { sprintf "%8s", $_} @row{@wanted}, "\n";
}
```

Which then gives:

```
 #Genera     columnA     columnC     columnN           
      x1           1           7           2           
      x2           5          13           5           
      x3         0.1           7         0.4
```

Comment: woh, didn't know about hash slices, i will thank you even i'm not the OP :)
but I don't understand how the `split` in `@row{@header} = split;` is equivalent to `split(/\s+/, $_)`

Comment: @Flying_whale: I suggest you spend some time reading the [documentation for split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). It makes it clear that a) omitting the string means that the contents of `$_` are split, b) omitting the pattern uses `" "` as the default pattern and that c) using `" "` as the pattern is equilvalent to using `\s+`. (Using `" "` also removes leading whitespace - but that's not important in this example. Perl's standard documentation is clear and detailed. I recommend it highly.

Comment: thanks a lot @DaveCross :)
I'm kind of new to perl (less than 3 month) and I still have a lot to learn ;)

Comment: thanks so much, it is how I want it, I'm learning perl by my self and some times it hard to me, again Thanks So Much to all of you  !!!!

Answer (score 2):

This program does as you ask. It expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, which can then be read using the empty "diamond operator" `<>` without explicitly opening it

Each non-blank line of the file is split into fields, and the header line is identified by the first starting with a hash symbol `#`

A call to `map` converts the `@wanted_fields` array into a list of indexes into `@fields` where those column headers appear and stores it in array `@idx`

This array is then used to slice the wanted columns from `@fields` for every line of input. The fields are printed, separated by tabs

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'first';

my @wanted_fields = qw/ columnA columnC columnN /;

my @idx;

while ( <> ) {
    next unless /\S/;

    my @fields = split;

    if ( $fields[0] =~ /^#/ ) {

        @idx = ( 0, map {
            my $wanted = $_;
            first { $fields[$_] eq $wanted } 0 .. $#fields;
        } @wanted_fields );
    }

    print join( "\t", @fields[@idx] ), "\n" if @idx;
}
```

#### output

```
#Genera columnA columnC columnN
x1  1   7   2
x2  5   13  5
x3  0.1 7   0.4
```

Comment: @abraham: Thank you: you're welcome. But you should eventually choose one of the answers and *accept* it if any of them has been useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

There are command line switches that are used for this kind of application:

```
perl -lnae 'print join "\t", @F[1,3,5]' file.txt
```

Switch `-a` automatically creates variable `@F` for each line, split by whitespace. So `@F[1,3,5]` is an array slice of elements 1, 3, and 5.

The downside of this, of course, is that you have to use the column numbers instead of the names.